# Rust fmt configuration for vertical chaining

Tags: rust, rustfmt

The following is what I desire to format to:

```
async fn main() {
    let req = reqwest::get("http://wttr.in/brisbane")
        .await
        .expect("Failed to get weather data")
        .text()
        .await;
}
```

This is what I get (unless it does not fit on the one line, then it will format it like above):

```
    let req = reqwest::get("http://wttr.in/brisbane").await.expect("Failed to get weather data").text().await;
```

I want it to always format vertically, regardless of width. How can I do this?

Comment: For all method chains?

Comment: Maybe set `chain_width` to 0? I didn't test that though.

Comment: am unsure what method chains exist, but if possible just want .xxx().yyy().zzz() to be vertically expanded @ChayimFriedman

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question, @ripbozo?